# How to compile many projects in one makefile

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

Simple question but I couldn't find any full answer online.

I have 3 projects, my desire outcome is that I run make and all 3 programs are transformed into executable files.

```sh
gcc -o server server.c
gcc -o server2 server2.c
gcc -o server3 server3.c
```

Is this achievable? How?

Comment: refer this : https://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/

Comment: @Bogota Thanks but none of those example references 3 separate projects in one makefile.

Comment: If you know how to write a makefile that builds one target, just do that three times: one for each target, in the same file.  Then at the start of the file add a rule that depends on all of them, like: `all: server server2 server3`.

Comment: @MadScientist do you want to post your comment as an answer? It did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MadScientist for answering my question in the comments. I wish I could give him rep for this answer.

The Makefile that worked for me was

```
.PHONY: all server server2 server3
all: server server2 server3


server: server.c
    gcc -o server server.c 
server2: server2.c
    gcc -o server2 server2.c 
server3: server3.c
    gcc -o server3 server3.c
```

After Makefile is created, enter `make` in the command line to execute the 3 gcc commands.

By default `make` will call `make all` which in sort will call server, server2, server3 as defined on this line `all: server server2 server3`.

I'm still not sure what `.PHONY` is all about.

Comment: You should use `.PHONY: all` but not the others.  If you're not sure what something does, it's best to not include it :).  The manual is your friend: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html

Comment: @MadScientist Can you explain why?

Comment: If you read the documentation link above and have specific questions about things you don't understand, I'm happy to answer them.  But, I don't want to just reiterate what is written in the documentation.